# Fetching record from XML on the base of condition using Linq or any other way in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, linq

I'm new to LINQ and trying to fetch record from the XML document using LINQ  so please help me with the Below scenario:

XML Document:

```
<ParsedResultSet>  
 <Orders_Renewals>
    <file_line_number>1</file_line_number>
    <issn>15338606</issn>
    <publisher_title_reference>ABC</publisher_title_reference>
    <journal_title>Music</journal_title>
    <publisher_subscription_reference>54562</publisher_subscription_reference>
    <agent_subscription_reference>86031</agent_subscription_reference>
  </Orders_Renewals>
  <Orders_Renewals>
    <file_line_number>2</file_line_number>
    <issn>15338606</issn>
    <publisher_title_reference></publisher_title_reference>
    <journal_title>Music1</journal_title>
    <publisher_subscription_reference>598782</publisher_subscription_reference>
    <agent_subscription_reference>86276</agent_subscription_reference>
  </Orders_Renewals>
  <Orders_Renewals>
    <file_line_number>3</file_line_number>
    <issn>15338606</issn>
    <publisher_title_reference>DEF</publisher_title_reference>
    <journal_title>Music2</journal_title>
    <publisher_subscription_reference>507682</publisher_subscription_reference>
    <agent_subscription_reference>31276</agent_subscription_reference>
  </Orders_Renewals>
</ParsedResultSet>
```

My searching condition like:

```
Select publisher_title_reference from Orders_Renewals where publisher_subscription_reference = '598782'and agent_subscription_reference = '31276'
```

Result Should be : `XYZ`

I have tried with below code but I'm not getting any ouput:

```
string xmlPath = @"D:\Temp\FileState" + "_" + xmlFileID;
                XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
                var XMLOrderCodeNode = from n in xml.Elements("Orders_Renewals")
                                       where n.Attribute("agent_subscription_reference").Value.ToString().Trim() == agentRefNbr
                                       select n.Attribute("publisher_title_reference").Value.ToString().Trim();
```

Please help me with the scenario and Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why should result be `XYZ`? `XYZ` isn't in your file?

Comment: Yes `agent_subscription_reference` is an attribute shared in XML doc  and I need only XYZ in my select query but its an requirement

Comment: It is not an attribute. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_el_vs_attr.asp

Comment: Oh Sorry my mistake that is an Element not an attribute but can you please give solution with my query it will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below.  You can add a where to filter as required :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var orders = doc.Descendants("Orders_Renewals").Select(x => new {
                file_line_number = (int)x.Element("file_line_number"),
                issn = (string)x.Element("issn"),
                reference = (string)x.Element("publisher_title_reference"),
                title = (string)x.Element("journal_title"),
                subscription = (string)x.Element("publisher_subscription_reference"),
                agent = (int)x.Element("agent_subscription_reference")
            }).ToList();

        int agentRefNbr = 86031;
        var results = orders.Where(x => x.agent == agentRefNbr).ToList();



        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`agent_subscription_reference` and `publisher_title_reference` are not attributes. Use this query to get the `Descendants` and then find the elements:

```
var XMLOrderCodeNode = from n in xml.Descendants("Orders_Renewals")
                        where n.Element("agent_subscription_reference").Value.ToString().Trim() == agentRefNbr
                        select n.Element("publisher_title_reference").Value.ToString().Trim();
```

When `agent_subscription_reference` is equal to `31276`, it should return `DEF` not `XYZ` as you have mentioned.